# Android Emulator won't display messages from React-Native

Tags: react-native

So I have installed my first app in React Native using the below commands

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
$ expo init confusion
$ cd confusion
$ yarn start
```

Then I see this terminal

[image: terminal message]

I have my emulator open from Android Studio and chose option **a**
This is what I see.

[image: emulator]

Is this correct? The welcoming message is in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Try to close the bundler then run , npm start

Comment: Have you tried by installing the expo app in your phone and scanning the qr code?

Comment: @GauravRoy Yes I have installed the expo app in my phone and scan the qr code.

Comment: @DevAS I tried that but still nothing. I really don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you interested in using expo?

Comment: Try to use a class instead of function and use componentDidMount to log any thing

Comment: @DevAS Still nothing

Comment: If won't work try to use react-native-CLI instead of Expo to avoid wasting your time ‍♂️

Comment: @DevAS. Ok so I will forget about Expo. How about react-native-CLI?

Comment: Take a Look at here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: This is how I installed and scaffolded the basic react-native app. All I need is a way to run it efficiently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202288/discussion-between-devas-and-theo).